Facing errors with scripts written in Selenium after updating Chrome to 127 verison
After updating my chrome to 127 version all my selenium test scripts started to raise error. Is anyone having the same issue?
I saw on one of the questions solution to this case by adding script  options.addArguments("--disable-search-engine-choice-screen");, but how can I add it to my script properly?
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

driver.get('https://www.google.com')
print(driver.title)

driver.quit()

Can anyone help?
I tried this and still cant get it worked:
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-search-engine-choice-screen")

service = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)

driver.get('https://www.google.com')
print(driver.title)

driver.quit()


What is the error you're seeing?

OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error: '/Users/user/.wdm/drivers/chromedriver/mac64/127.0.6533.72/chromedriver-mac-arm64/THIRD_PARTY_NOTICES.chromedriver'

With Chrome Version 127.0.6533.73 (Official Build) (arm64) on MacOS 14.5, Python 3.12.4 and selenium 4.23.1 the following code runs without error:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ChromeOptions

options = ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless")

with webdriver.Chrome(options=options) as driver:
    driver.get("https://www.google.com")
    print(driver.title)

Output:
Google

Note how the Chrome driver is constructed
